# How to fix Automator date-time script in Mojave

Tags: automator

having issues getting a simple one-line automator script to work under Mojave.

An old script I used to have installed and use (built in Automator) no longer works...

The script in automator was as follows:

```
# return 24hr date and time
date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

The above is all what was set in Automator.

After installing the script through the automator file named "24-hr-time.workflow" I set up a keyboard shortcut to trigger the workflow to run.

I set it so that it runs as a service under System Preference, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Services, 24-hr-time (under the text heading).

Well, it doesn't work any more. Not sure why.  I thought it may have been because of a keyboard shortcut conflict with another function.  So, I tried several different ones and the problem persists.  Such that when I trigger the service by using the shortcut keys, nothing happens.  Basically, it just doesn't work.

What do I do?

OS: I've upgraded to Mojave (10.14.4).

Thank you.

The desired result is that when I press the shortcut key combination (e.g. Cmd+8), that the 24-hr-time workflow runs, thereby inserting the date and time into whatever application is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

I created a Quick Action in Automator (Services are now called Quick Actions).

[image]

I configured it like this:

[image]

I saved it as TodayDate. I gave it a keyboard shortcut in Preferences:

[image]

I used my keyboard shortcut in a TextEdit document and it worked fine:

[image]

Comment: I believe I've shown you how to do it. Your response, please?

Comment: Matt, hi sorry for the delay. I spent a little time recently and it still is not working for me.  Can't understand for the life of me why it isn't. I'm going to try to look at it again tomorrow and I'll let you know.  Thank you so much for the feedback and for your patience.

Comment: Try doing EXACTLY what I did.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try again.  I tried doing exactly that; must have been my failure. I will try and report back.  Again, thank you.